# Use both subdomains and subdirectories in Magento multistore?

Tags: magento, subdomain, subdirectory, multistore

I currently have a store in Magento with several store views for different languages as example.com/sv/, example.com/fi/ etc. Now I want to add a store to a subdomain as test.example.com but I can't make it work.

I added a new store and a new store view for the subdomain and then changed the Base URL for this. I have created the subdomain and it points to the location of the magento installation. I have also added different lines in the .htaccess file, tried some variations of the ones below.

```
SetEnvIf Host .*newstore.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=newstore
SetEnvIf Host .*newstore.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*newstore\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:newstore]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*newstore\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

But nothing works. When I try to access the subdomain I get redirected to the main store. But I can access the new store as a subdirectory, it's supposed to be like this test.example.com but I have to write example.com/test.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Update 15-04-09

I found a redirect in the .htaccess file that caused the subdomain to be redirected to the main store. I removed it and now I can access the subdomain but the page is just white and it says "Index of /" etc. so I don't get the magento store view.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in my .htaccess that does what you want:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^it\.mystore\.com$"    MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website MAGE_RUN_CODE=ws_it
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^pt\.mystore\.com$"    MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website MAGE_RUN_CODE=ws_pt

SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^fr\.mystore\.be$" MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store MAGE_RUN_CODE=fr_be
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^nl\.mystore\.be$" MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store MAGE_RUN_CODE=nl_be
```

Also make sure you have properly defined the **Base URL** (in your example: test.example.com) in System > Configuration > General Web > Secure *and* Unsecure for your new website or store

Comment: I've tried this but it still doesn't work. I found a redirect that caused some problems so now I only get a white page that says "Index of /" etc. I still don't get the new store view.

Comment: Do you see the index.php, cron.php... in the list below "Index of" ?

Comment: No I don't. No files are listed on the page.

Comment: The subdomain is pointing to the same IP as the main domain. I guess it could be something with the setup on the server. I have a folder "www" that contains two folders "html" and "www.test.com". In the "html" folder there is only a .htaccess file and in the other there is also a folder named "html" which contains the Magento installation. Maybe I only get to this first "html" folder?

Comment: You probably have to configure something in apache (look for httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf) to make your new subdomain point into the right Magento installation folder. To answer your last question, yes I guess.